# Importing table values from yahoo finance using the IMPORTHTML function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, html-table, google-sheets-formula

The following function in Google Sheets worked until last Friday:

> =index(IMPORTHTML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"&B1&"/key-statistics?p="&B1&"","table",
> 2),5,2)

This function would go to the statistics section in Yahoo Finance and extract the Market Cap from a stock. It stopped working today and I'm not sure why.

I tried using the following command in the Chrome console to get the table number and played with the table indices for the IMPORTHTML function but no luck:

> var i = 1; [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("table"),
> function(x) { console.log(i++, x); });

Did Yahoo do something to make this no longer work? OR are my indices just wrong now?

Comment: Can I ask you about the sample URL and the result values you want? Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the value of "B1". I apologize for this.

Comment: Hi Tanaike: The value B1 is the cell in google sheets that represents the user inputted ticker (e.g. AAPL = Apple)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, the value of "B1" is `AAPL = Apple`. Is my understanding correct? And, can I ask you about the result values you want? Unfortunately, I cannot understand about it from your replying. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using every IMPORT formula of Google Sheets and unfortunately, it is returning the same error every single time.

[image]

It seems that Yahoo changed some things in their website and it resulted to the import formula not to work anymore.

I suggest finding another website/data source that will give you the same information that you need. Or if you want to stay with Yahoo Finance, you can explore and try to use their API if you want ([link-here](https://blog.api.rakuten.net/api-tutorial-yahoo-finance/)).

EDIT: Upon further checking, it seems that this issue is only happening on some of the tickers and some webpage in Yahoo Finance. Another option would be waiting for Yahoo to fix the issue.

Comment: For me this is the case for every single ticker. I wonder if they are now actively preventing scraping of data in some way

Comment: I think that is the most possible case to assume right now. This seems to affect a lot of people right now.

Comment: If the answer helped you with this concern, please do upvote/accept in order for others to know the answer if ever they encounter the same problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers